# Build an http webapp server and opening it from a fyne app on android

Tags: android, go, http, web-applications, fyne

I tried to build an HTTP server and opening it from a fyne app on android. If I run from the fyne app from the source folder it works but if I build it and try to run it on android the webapp breaks.

`

```
package main

import (
    //"log"
    "net/http"
    //"strings"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/data/binding"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"

    //"fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "net/url"

    "fmt"
)

//var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

var mainapp fyne.App

var MainTorrent string //magnet
var MainFile string    //filepath
var AppIsClosing bool

func main() {
    mainapp = app.New()
    //mainapp.Settings().SetTheme(&myTheme{})
    //mainapp.SetIcon(resourceAppiconPng)
    mainwin := mainapp.NewWindow("wetorrent")
    mainwin.Resize(fyne.NewSize(400, 710))
    go startServer() //03
    AppIsClosing = false

    tabs := container.NewAppTabs(
        container.NewTabItem("Home", homeScreen(mainwin)),
    )

    tabs.SetTabLocation(container.TabLocationTop)

    mainwin.SetContent(tabs)

    mainwin.ShowAndRun()
    AppIsClosing = true

}
func homeScreen(win fyne.Window) fyne.CanvasObject {
    data := binding.BindStringList(
        //&[]string{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"},
        &[]string{},
    )

    list := widget.NewListWithData(data,
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
            return widget.NewLabel("template")
        },
        func(i binding.DataItem, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
            o.(*widget.Label).Bind(i.(binding.String))
        })

    add := widget.NewButton("Open New Webapp Tab", func() {
        //val := fmt.Sprintf("Item %d", data.Length()+1)
        //data.Append(val)
        openNewWebappTab()
        fmt.Println("coool")

    })
    return container.NewBorder(add, nil, nil, nil, list)
}

func openNewWebappTab() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
    mainapp.OpenURL(u) //

}

func startServer() {
    openNewWebappTab()

    //
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./Webapp"))
    http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/", fs))

    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

I was expecting to have an android app that will be able to run the webapp on android. How can I get the folder were to put the  webapp on android and can the fyne compile command help me copy the web app?

Comment: I'm wondering have you found a solution for that? or totally abodnanded fyne for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Storage is different on each OS, a Fyne app knows it can use files at the location specified by `App.Storage().RootURI()`.